# Check substrings of a string value includes any dictionary words in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, substring

I am wondering that there is any function in Python to check substrings of a string value including any dictionary words.

ex. `check_str = "!$#apple!ed"`

`check_str` includes `"apple"` which is a dictionary word, and I want to check if there is any way we can check that.

Comment: in your case how are the words delimited? Is "ple" a possible candidate?

Comment: it's broad how you define dictionary words but you should use `regex` to parse the string of anything that is not a letter

Comment: Should `"ed"` be a word too? What if the substring overlaps, e.g. `"app"` is a word inside `"apple"`. Do you want all of the results as a list or just a true/false?

Comment: Have you done any research?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is borderline natural language processing, but a naive solution is to load up a list of valid words from a text file, split the string into chunks of alphabetical characters and look each one up in the dictionary.

```
>>> import re
>>> import requests
>>> s = "!$#apple!ed"
>>> url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dwyl/english-words/master/words_dictionary.json"
>>> words = requests.get(url).json()
>>> alpha_chunks = re.findall(r"[a-z]+", s, re.I)
>>> [x for x in alpha_chunks if x.lower() in words]
['apple', 'ed']
```

It turns out `"ed"` is a perfectly valid dictionary word in addition to `"apple"`, so if you intend to reject that, use a word list that suits your needs. Also, the dictionary requested above is 6 mb, so you'd likely want to cache it depending on what your use case is.

Comment: I would suggest: `alpha_chunks = re.findall(r"\b[a-z]+\b", s, re.I): [x for x in alpha_chunks if x.lower() in words]`. In other words, modify the regex to use word boundaries and ignore case but then force the matched words to lower case for lookup. That way you can find words that are capitalized. Because 'e' is in `words`, you would like to ignore `10.0e+3` and hence the need for using `\b`.